# Laravel framework upgrade 4.0 --> 4.1

Tags: php, laravel-4

I desided to use morph relation in the site's database and I need at lease laravel 4.1 version for this. (now I have 4.0.11)
But I couldn't manage to do this by myself:
1) First I followed the instruction below(official documentation)
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-4.1  (half of the references to git are dead)
But didn't go throuth as it says that __construct of Applicationi should get the Request object (not the string)

2) I found another way through creating command of update here http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/artisan-command-to-upgrade-to-41

After typing "php artisan upgrade 4.1" (without option it notices that 4.0 is the last version for me) And it seemed that the update has been completed successfully. However it points to the same problem:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Application::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given, called in /home/roman/cblog/bootstrap/app.php on line 14 and defined in /home/roman/cblog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 99
```

I do recognize that the problem is in exception which is thrown due to creation of Application istance in app.php:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(realpath(__DIR__.'/../'));
```

As received String insted of Request. If we see in Application.php:

```
public function __construct(Request $request = null)
    {
        $this['request'] = $this->createRequest($request);
        $this->registerBaseServiceProviders();
    }
```

And here version remained old:

```
/**
     * The Laravel framework version.     
     * @var string
       */
    const VERSION = '4.0.11';
```

Maybe someone could give me a hint what I missed on upgrading. Or maybe I'd better to upgrade to newer version?

Comment: First I tried to update to L5. And it appeared to be continuous configuration hell. I used two big articles for that purpose: 
one is official 
http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade 
and another one from the blog
https://mattstauffer.co/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5
Both are useless: so many things to change beginning from the controllers' namespacing, getting rid of filters, changing router file(implicit use of controller classes) and finishing by some bugs of version 5 which should be fixed one by one using google search.

Comment: After getting exhausted of my trials to update to L5 I decided to update consequently one by one version without passing any middle version.

Comment: And installed a brand new laravel 4.1 project using composer. The only thing to do are:
- change composer(add packeges to section "require" from 4.0 project composer). Run "composer update"; 
- change app.php, database.php files as per ones from the former project; 
- copy Controllers,Models,Views folders the from old 4.0 project; 
- copy Public folder from old project(keeping the same ierarchy); 
- in my particular case I had to copy app\includes folder as I have some additional php scripts there (you may have to copy lang,tests,command folder if you have something specific in 4.0 project)

Comment: ...and that's it. Looks much simpler than looking through many framework engine's files.
I believe the instruction suits another versions update as well.